# Best way to prevent sql "injection" when using column as variable

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-injection, pymssql

I'm using pymssql to Update, Drop, and Add columns to a MS SQL server. the columns are sadly variables set by external sources such as reading the database, reading from another database. Now i'm trying to prevent "bad" sql to get through as i don't know exactly what the other database gives me.

```
'ALTER TABLE tablenameA ADD  [' + columnname + '] varchar(25) NULL'
'ALTER TABLE tablenameA DROP COLUMN ['+columnname+']'
('UPDATE tablenameA SET [' + columnname + ']=%s WHERE id = 2', value)
```

Now i can't use a whitelist as i don't know what column names is to be added, my only other option i can think of is to use a blacklist, but i was wondering if there maybe exists a third option.

(The column names are gotten from a column in a table with type string)

Comment: You could use [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

Comment: From the same `QUOTENAME` documentation: *Returns a **Unicode string** with the delimiters added to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier.* A string still won't do here as it doesn't create a complete SQL statement.

Comment: Would querying the database once with `SELECT QUOTENAME(%s)`, then interpolating that into the query do...?

Comment: @deceze: that would work, indeed.

Comment: I'm less worried about my UPDATE as i'm using a select for the column names and not from table rows. 

The other database i'm selecting from is an Oracle DB where I query for row values and not column names. This is where i'm worried there might be something lurking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transact-SQL has a function to turn a SQL string into a safe object name: [`QUOTENAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). Use it around a bind parameter to have the database driver provide a properly quoted SQL object:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT QUOTENAME(%s)', (columnname,))
quoted_columnname, = next(cursor)
```

Now you can use *that* string in a new query:

```
query = 'ALTER TABLE tablenameA ADD {} varchar(25) NULL'.format(quoted_columnname)
```

etc. I used `str.format()` to insert the string here, rather than use string concatenation. Note that the `[...]` square brackets are no longer needed; `QUOTENAME()` took care of that.